# setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do simple click timer. But my do something wrong and my clearInterval do not work. The counting proceed and clear interval don't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
    <head>
    <script>
    var seconds = 10;
    var clicks = 0;
    var a=0;
    function start()
    {
        a++;
        if(a > 0 && a < 2)
        {
        var interval;
            if(minute == 0)
            {
                clearInterval(interval) 
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                interval = setInterval(function(){
                seconds--;
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = seconds;
                    },1000);
            }
        }

    }


    function goClick()
    {
        if(a==1)
        {
        clicks++;
        document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    }
    </script>
        <meta charset='utf-8'> 
        <title> Try to find </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">how many clicks you can do for 10 seconds </h1>
        <button onclick="start();" >start </button> <br />
        <button onclick="goClick();" >click </button> <br />
        <div><p> count : <span id="span"></span> </p></div>
         <br />
        <div><p> time : <span id="time"></span> </p></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `a` is integer, `a > 0 && a < 2` is the same as `a === 1`.

Comment: Load your page in Chrome with the Developer Tools open and look at the error message. [Here's a tutorial on the Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is that interval canceling part is placed where it will never run. Put it in the interval function itself:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    seconds--;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = seconds;    
    if( seconds === 0 ) {
        clearInterval( interval );
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Work perfect now. Thank you Juhana!